# Inserting a new tag in existing XML file using file IO instead of parsers

Tags: c++, xml

I have an existing custom xml file for which I need to add a tag basically append it to the end of root node. But as the xml format will not be changed it can be safely assumed that parsing is not required and only need to add this tag in the end of the file.

XML format:

```
<links>
...
...
<url type="search">www.google.com</url>
</links>
```

In the above xml file, I would like to add the  tag.

File operation suggests we cannot add in the middle of the file. Can anyone suggest other approaches?

Comment: Read the file into memory (into a string presumably), make the change you want to the string, then write the whole string out to a file.

Comment: Why does the tag need to be at the end? XML entries should not depend on order. What problem are you trying to solve here?

Comment: @RoQuOTriX Yes its just for my testing that new entries will be added to the end of the file. The exact problem is that there is an xml created during an operation on the fly and a new feature (radio btn) added which requires this xml to be updated before going to final step if selected. Unable to pass this radio button's data to XML object, I am thinking to add it at the end of the operation.

Comment: "XML entries should not depend on order" - as a general statement, that's nonsense. Most XML is used in document processing, after all.

Answer (score 0):

"Safely" is always relative. You can never "safely" assume that you can process XML without parsing unless you are 100% in control of the process that generates the XML, and are confident you will remain so.

And if you are in control of the XML, then I would suggest maintaining it as two files: a content.xml file that holds everything except the root element, and a wrapper.xml file that references content.xml as an external entity:

```
<!DOCTYPE links [
<!ENTITY e SYSTEM "content.xml">
]>
<links>&e;</links>
```

and then you can use a normal file append operation on `content.xml` to add to the content.